# coordinate encription

Tags: no-computers

today I found myself in front of the following codified text:
MzIgVCA2NTg3MjYgNDg1MTY0Nw0KMzIgVCA2NTc5OTkgNDg1MzExMw0KMzIgVCA2NTc0MDUgNDg1MjMxM A0KMzIgVCA2NTg2MzkgNDg1MTgzMg0KMzIgVCA2NTc1NDIgNDg1MzY4NA0KMzIgVCA2NTgwMTMgNDg1MTQ 0Nw0KMzIgVCA2NTc3MzMgNDg1MzMxNQ0KMzIgVCA2NTcyMjggNDg1MzM0Mw0KMzIgVCA2NTc4NDggNDg1 MTY3OA==

I know that the text is composed of geographic coordinates.

and that the text: "MzIgVCA2NTc0MDUgNDg1MjMxM A0KMzIgVCA2NTg2MzkgNDg1MTgzMg0KMzIgVCA2NTc1NDIgNDg1MzY4NA"

corresponds to the coordinates:

32 T 657405 4852310
32 T 658639 4851832
32 T 657542 4853684

MzIgVCA2 NT    c0MDU    gND g1M   jMxMA 0K -> 32 T 657405 4852310
MzIgVCA2 NT    g2Mzk     gND g1M   TgzMg 0K  -> 32 T 658639 4851832
MzIgVCA2 NT    c1NDI      gND g1M   zY4NA 0K  -> 32 T 657542 4853684

what is the encryption key?

Comment: Do you yourself know the answer? If you don't, the no-computers tag seems a bit unfair; you have no idea how much effort it would require.

Comment: If this is a puzzle you found somewhere else, could you please edit the question to say (as exactly as possible) where? There are two reasons. The first is that it's a rule around here, to make sure there's no suspicion of plagiarism. The second is that knowing some context may help figure out what's going on with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a base64 cipher, as indicated by the two equal signs at the end

The text is deciphered into the following:

> 32 T 658726 4851647
> 32 T 657999 4853113
> 32 T 657405 4852310
> 32 T 658639 4851832
> 32 T 657542 4853684
> 32 T 658013 4851447
> 32 T 657733 4853315
> 32 T 657228 4853343
> 32 T 657848 4851678